# Did Golobulus witness the exodus to the Himalayas?

Tags: gi-joe, gi-joe-the-movie

In the 1987 animated film *[G.I. Joe: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.I._Joe:_The_Movie)*, Golobulus — the supreme leader of Cobra-La and the various creatures that inhabit it — uses the Web of Remembrance to explain to the human members of Cobra the "truth" of Earth's history:

- The world had once been dominated by a flourishing culture of intelligent organisms that were scientifically gifted and had mastered biological technology.
- Their society all but collapsed due to the Ice Age, and the survivors were forced to retreat to the Himalayas, where they established "Cobra-La", a refuge where they have resided ever since.
- The world's power vacuum was filled by the evolving Homo Sapiens, who eventually developed inorganic cities and technologies that members of Cobra-La find repulsive and blasphemous.
- Golobulus himself sent Cobra Commander (a once brilliant scientist) out into the human world to destabilize human culture and prepare the world for the resurgence of their people.

I have tried searching, but cannot find anything concerning Golobulus' age.

[image: Golobulus]

**In particular, was Golobulus alive during the retreat of his people during the Ice Age?**

I can't seem to find anything regarding the lifespans of members of Cobra-La.  Given their adeptness with organic systems, they may have been able to develop extremely long lifespans — perhaps even immortality.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Yojoe.com](https://www.yojoe.com/action/87/golobulus.shtml) he has achieved immortality via symbiosis, but it does not state when he was born:

[image: Golobulus file card from a 1987 series six action figure; the text is reproduced below]

> Descended from the serpent kings of pre-history, Golobulus rules over Cobra-La, a hidden, secret valley in the Himalayas where the high priests of the Bio-Mechanical cult have created a technology based society on living organisms. The buildings of Cobra La are really colonies of crustaceans, and the clothes of inhabitants are as alive as the people who wear them. **Golobulus has achieved immortality through symbiosis**...at the cost of his humanity.
>
> "The plates of Golobulus' body armor are living mutations of lobsters and crabs, each genetically altered to perform a specific function and bred for the tensile strength of their chitinous shells. Over the centuries, so much of Golobulus' body parts have been replaced or bio-mechanically altered that very little of the original is left except for his brain and his central nervous system."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This appears to be half of an answer; if he's immortal he _could_ have been there, but without establishing when he was born it's still an open question.  Also, it's good to quote original sources as accurately as possible; I will demonstrate.